# Is warning on newly partitioned 4TB hard drive after 16.04 install a problem?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have just completed installing 16.04 on a new 4TB hard drive. After the install I looked at the partitions and see the following:

[image: GParted screen shot]

output from fdisk -l shows the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 36185296-9627-4D00-B4BE-E0EC94374064

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2        4096 7780610047 7780605952  3.6T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  7780610048 7814035455   33425408   16G Linux swap
```

Do I need to take care of this warning and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sda1 is flagged bios_grub, so it does not have a filesystem -- it is just raw disk space for grub's core.img file.  You need such a partition on a GPT disk booting legacy, but not the older MSDOS partitioned disks because there was room on the MSDOS disks after the partition table, but before partition 1.

---

Bullet #3 under the Warning is "There is no filesystem availale (unformatted)" which is the case for that partition.  Ignore the warning.

Comment: Because the bios_grub does have a GUID and is defined, gparted should not be showing an  error. But it is looking at formats and since unformatted thinks it is wrong. Also same error on Windows "System Reserved" which is another partition required by Windows but unformatted.

Comment: So should I ignore the error? I want to start using the system but I also want to be sure it will be a stable platform. From what ubfan1 says, I can ignore it because it is 'normal' for sda1 to have this error because it is just raw space for the core.img file. On the other hand, oldfred says that GParted should not be showing an error. Should I be concerned about this error/warning?